# GROUP by version and display by row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+----------+--------+
|   name   | version|
+----------+--------+
| book     |      2 |
| book     |      1 |
| book     |      1 |
| pen      |      1 |
| pen      |      2 |
| pen      |      2 |
| pen      |      2 |
| paper    |      1 |
+----------+--------+
```

I have the table above and i want to make a query to group by name and count by version(row) 
Result:

```
+----------+--------+--------+
|   name   | version| count  |
+----------+--------+--------+
| book     |      1 |      2 |
| book     |      2 |      1 |
| pen      |      1 |      1 |
| pen      |      2 |      3 |
| paper    |      1 |      1 |
| paper    |      2 |      0 |
+----------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: That's a basic GROUP BY, with COUNT().

Comment: select name, version, count(*) as count from yourtable group by name, version

Comment: But after your edit it became somewhat trickier.

Comment: @RanjitSingh . . . Please explain the last row.  I suspect it should be paper/2/0.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - yes I missed the last row, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes edited already

Answer (score 0):

The query would be

```
SELECT name, version, count(*) as count
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY name, version
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all name/version combinations, then use a `cross join` to generate all rows and then `left join` to bring in the existing data:

```
select n.name, v.version, count(t.name)
from (select distinct name from t) n cross join
     (select distinct version from t) v left join
     t
     on t.name = n.name and t.version = v.version
group by n.name, v.version
order by n.name, v.version;
```